# how to call checkbox value from sql to display on form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

am doing this but not working only apply in first record  its working in insert and update 
i stored in sql as true or false

Sub db_load()

```
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim pringdata As String = "SELECT custcode_" & _
  ",custname_" & _
  ",custname2_" & _
  ",phone_" & _
  ",mobile_" & _
  ",custadd_" & _
  ",date_" & _
  ",cutomerzone_ " & _
  ",check_ " & _
  " FROM custInfo  "

    Dim sqlconload As New SqlConnection(sqlcon)
    sqlconload.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(pringdata, sqlconload)
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "custInfo")

    For i As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 To -1

        If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("check_") = "true" Then
            checkActive.Checked = True
        Else
            checkActive.Checked = False
        End If
    Next



    sqlconload.Close()
```

Comment: Your for .. loop is really weird, probably you mean `For i As Integer = 0 to ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count  -1`

Answer (score 0):

I gather you are referring to a specific customer since you're only setting a single checkbox? You'll need to modify your query to match that.

Next, examine how you're storing the "check" column. In most cases, converting to Bool will resolve it but you may have to special case it based on available values.

Also, if the field you're looking at could be null, you'll have to account for that as well.

Here's a good pattern to follow that properly disposes of resources such as connections, commands, and readers.

```
Public Sub db_load()
    Using cn = New SqlConnection(sqlcon)
        cn.Open()
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT custcode,custname,custname2,phone,mobile,custadddate,customerzone,check FROM custInfo", cn)
            Using dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If dr.Read Then
                    checkActive.Checked = CBool(dr("check"))
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```